# Selection of co related variables for ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, regularization

I'm a newbie to machine learning. I'm working on a dataset to predict a target variable in terms of the independent variables. In the dataset the independent variables few are very highly correlated . correlation coefficient is 1.

I used ridge regression since it will take care of the correlated variables.

The algorithm is penalizing all the correlated variables and taking only one among them.

Can someone throw light on how the variable selection is done for ridge regression in presence of correlated variables.

Comment: Ridge regression doesn't do variable selection because not all of them would go to zero.